# Minus a day in DATEDIFF query

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

If a user selects a date between `"2015-08-27 to 2015-08-29"` then 29 is considered his checkout date so I want to output the rates of 27 & 28.

Right now this code below outputs 3 days, it just need to output 2 days

database

[image]

```
$pdo = $dbo->prepare(
    "SELECT r.*, rr.rid, SUM(ABS(DATEDIFF(:ci, :co) * rr.rate)) as totalsum, rr.sdate, rr.edate 
    FROM rooms r 
    LEFT JOIN rates as rr ON r.id=rr.rid
    WHERE r.id NOT IN (SELECT room_id FROM reservation as b WHERE (b.checkout <= :ci 
    AND b.checkin >= :co) OR (b.checkout >= :ci AND b.checkin <= :co)) 
    AND (rr.sdate >= :ci AND rr.edate <=:co) OR (rr.sdate <=:ci AND rr.edate >=:co)
    GROUP BY rr.rid, r.room_name");                           
//$pdo->bindValue(':stat', 'confirm', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo->bindParam(':ci', $check_in, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo->bindParam(':co', $check_out, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if (!$pdo->execute()) {
    print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
} else {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Unclear question. What are your tables (show structure & data sample)?What does the query returns? What result are you expecting?

Comment: right now the query is outputting 3 days rates it just need to output 2 days

Comment: then dont use <= but just < as you want less than checkout day

Comment: ...or you can do DATEDIFF(...)-1 to remove the extra day

Comment: Both doesn't work i changed `<=` to `<` and tried `DATEDIFF(...)-1`

Comment: No worries, i solved it already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just change my `check out string` from this

```
$check_out =  date("Y-m-d" strtotime($_POST['co'])
```

to

```
$check_out = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($_POST['co'])));
```

And remove the `DATEDIFF() & ABS()` in the query like this below

```
SELECT r.*, rr.rid, SUM(rr.rate) as totalsum, rr.sdate, rr.edate 
FROM rooms r 
LEFT JOIN rates as rr ON r.id=rr.rid
WHERE rr.sdate >= :ci AND rr.edate <= :co
GROUP BY rr.rid, r.room_name
```

Done.

Answer (score 3):

You may not even need to solve it in PHP use in your query something like:

```
DATE_SUB(final_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

That should be equivalent to (final_date - 1 day)

Comment: or just `final_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Answer (score 1):

In MySql u can use simply DATE_ADD(checkout_date,INTERVAL -1 DAY).It will decrease 1 day from your checkout date
then u can count date diff correctly

```
DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(checkout_date,INTERVAL -1 DAY),checkin_Date)
```